# how to check the length of a field inside mongodb field and return only its 150 first characters

Tags: mongodb, meteor

how to check the length of a field inside mongodb field and return only its 150 first characters?

i have looked in mongoDB query string or update operators, but couldn't find this thing.

basically i have a blog which obviously has some posts, so my post document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "XCGCvb8tEbWCbQk7S",
    "author" : "Boaz Hoch",
    "date" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 12:57:49 GMT",
    "desc" : "string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-string-",
    "metaDesc" : "first post",
    "metaKeywords" : "first,post",
    "metaTitle" : "first Post",
    "title" : "first Post"
}
```

so what i want to do it to take the desc field, which is the description of the post and slice it to the first 150 characters, so in the posts page i would have only a tiny bit of the whole post, and add "..." to signal for "continue reading".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First alternative: you can create a template helper

```
Template.postsListTemplate.helpers({
  shortDesc: function() {
    return this.desc.substring(0,150);
  }
});
```

Another alternative would be to use a transform function on your posts collection

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts", {
  transform: function (doc) {
    doc.shortDesc = doc.desc.substring(0,150);
    return doc; 
  }
});
```

A better alternative would be to store the short version eg `shortdesc` within your document during insert/update as a separate property, therefore in your posts publication, you can send over that, and in your singlepost publication, you can send the actual `desc`. This would optimize your publication and save you the bandwidth of sending the whole post contents to a list page where you need only the first few characters.

Comment: Thanks, i haven't thought on the helper option, but both the transform and new field "shortDesc" was in my mind, just wasn't sure which is better. actually i'm not sure if option 3 ( new field ) is better then doing helper on the template, ill check both option. Thanks again :)

Comment: Template seems to be the preferred way and much easier to follow in your code. If you end up publishing a lot of posts to your post list page, you will definitely see the advantage of publishing only what will be exactly required on your page/template. There's great performance gain.

Comment: @BoazHoch side note - if you happen to be using [underscore string](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/underscore-string-latest), `_.prune` is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Hey David, thanks for notifying me, i have checked the [underscore string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) and it looks like a prefect match. thanks